# Interrupting rospy.spin() or writing a custom loop that does the equivalent

Tags: ros, rospy, service, spin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is there a way to exit the rospy.spin() loop without completely shutting down the node?

Or possibly is there a way to write my own equivalent rospy.spin() loop which answers service calls periodically until I stop it?

Any help or comments are appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252545/interrupting-rospy.spin()-or-writing-a-custom-loop-that-does-the-equivalent./) by [lwoiceshyn](https://answers.ros.org/users/29129/lwoiceshyn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The code of rospy.spin can be found on [github/roscom](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/kinetic-devel/clients/rospy/src/rospy/client.py#L118)

It boils down to

```
while not rospy.core.is_shutdown():
    rospy.rostime.wallsleep(0.5)
```

So you can write your node around this loop and leave the loop whenever you want.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-21**:
`rospy.spin()` is not even really needed to have a properly working ROS python node. `rospy.spin()` is just provided to have something that allows a similar control flow to be setup to how `roscpp` does things.